Let's get critical: Mar 2015 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Cryptography Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

Do any stream ciphers with aperiodic keystreams exist?

Net Score: 5 (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)


Definition of the Decryption oracle

Net Score: 5 (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)


Finding $x$'s parity in the discrete log problem

Net Score: 5 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)


Why are some x-coordinates unsuitable for an ECDSA generator point?

Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)


Is it possible: Derived key based on variable number of private keys?

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)


ElGamal and Schnorr groups

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)


Diffie-Hellman Application

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)


Additional Data in AEAD (Chacha20-poly1305 libsodium)

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)


Save the last cycle in GCM GHASH calculation

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)


Generate secure password hashes without access to PBKDF2 or bcrypt

Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)

